# Android:Stop or mute the mediaplayer but for all activities

Tags: android, media-player

I am developing a Quiz game application which is being developed completely but at various activities of my game different type of sounds files are played on every correct and wrong answer and respective theme sounds also plays at background.

But the problem arises when i want to stop or mute and start all the instances of media player running in various activities on click of mute and sound button in launcher activity.Can anyone help me out to bring out a logic of achieving this.I have dig into the logic a lot but cant find any concept to achieve this thats why no code to show.Because its totally logic based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a global class that contains "static" mediaplayer(s). When you need to stop, start or pause a mediaplayer, you can use

```
Global.mp1.stop();
Global.mp2.pause();
Global.mp3.start();
```

etc.